# Can the IntelliJ IDEA run tab have color?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot application inside IntelliJ IDEA and noticed a difference if I run it via the run tab (run menu) and via manual command from the terminal tab.

If I run it through a maven run target (play button), I do not see any colors inside the 'run' tab. If I run it via 'mvn spring-boot:run from the 'terminal' tab I see the pretty color highlights. The maven run configuration also runs the same command, spring-boot:run.

Application started from the play button/run configuration (run tab):
[image: run tab]
Application started from the terminal tab via mvn spring-boot:run (terminal tab):
[image: terminal tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IDEA 2017.1 EAP I'm getting colours even if I'm just running the application with the standard run command

[image: Colours in IDEA]

Edit:
Might be that Community edition doesn't support Spring Boot at all (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

[image]

Comment: Is that a Spring or Spring Boot run configuration type? I am on the Community Edition and that run configuration type is not available. I can only run the project through Maven (spring-boot:run) or the main method like any Java regular application. Do you still see the colors in the run tab if you start the application as mentioned above?

Comment: It's Spring Boot, that's what's automatically generated from the when I press  Shift+Ctrl+F10. And I'm running Ultimate edition, but for the EAP I think they are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately they are also separate and there is a Community Edition EAP version. I guess I can try the Ultimate version in trial mode to see if that is the issue. If it is, that's really strange that they would enforce this on purpose--no color on Maven/Java Application run configurations in the run tab.

Comment: See my edit, I think you're right about the community edition.

Comment: Yes, I knew it doesn't support it officially, but it's strange the colors don't show up in the run window and they do in the Terminal :) Just verified that they also don't show up in the Ultimate edition for a Maven or Application run configuration. Only way to get them is to run through a Spring Boot configuration in Ultimate or through Maven in the Terminal tab.

Answer (score 9):

Inside **build.gradle**, add the following block to get colorized log output when running your Spring Boot app inside IntelliJ IDEA via `gradle bootRun`.

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ["-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS"]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's supported for the [Spring Boot Run/Debug configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140158) type. It explicitly passes

```
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

JVM option enabling the color output.

As far as I know, ANSI colors support is not available when you run it in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven or Gradle configurations in the built-in console. Feature request [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Best answer, but not completly right about the Maven/Gradle integration: I think you can always add the System Property mentioned above to your VM arguments, so Maven and Gradle configurations will also become colorful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the very same output also in the Community Edition with the previously mentioned option:

```
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

Simply go to "Run" -> "Edit Configurations..." and add the option in the "VM options:" field for your main class.